# Building a multi table relationship in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models in Rails:

```
Player
Match
Series
```

And a Post model:

```
Post
```

I want to link each post to one of the above model. Need to create a new table that will have

```
Object_type - player or match or series
Object_id - Id of above object
Post_id
```

Is there a built in way to create such relationship in rails? and easily access a player's post like player.posts? (that will filter for object_type = 'player' in this relationship table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Polymorphic Associations to manage relationships. Refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 0):

You can use STI (single table inheritance) for that for more detail read follow this link

http://www.therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails