# One to Many in Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, polymorphic-associations

Based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880755/building-a-multi-table-relationship-in-rails-activerecord), I am building a polymorphic association. I wanted to have one to many relationship as well. So I have created a new table/model `posties`/`Posty` to manage this relationship

A post can belong to multiple players and multiple teams.

Models:

```
class Posty < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :posts
    belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posties
    has_many :players, :through => :posties
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts,:as => :target, :through => :posties
end
```

Tables:

```
  create_table "posties", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "posty_id"
    t.string   "posty_type", limit: 30
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.date     "post_date"
    t.string   "title"
  end

  create_table "players", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

When I do, `Player.find(1).posts`, I get

`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :posties in model Player`

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do away with this intermediary Posty class, as only need a join table/model for a many-many association.But that aside, you need to fix the setup.

The polymorphic column names should be based on the association name.

```
create_table "posties", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "target_id"
  t.string   "target_type", limit: 30
  t.integer  "post_id"
end

class Posty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posties
  has_many :players, :through => :posties, :as => :target
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posties, :as => :target
  has_many :posts, :through => :posties
end
```

Edit:

I better just add that this probably still won't work. Im fairly sure you cannot have a has_many though a polymorphic association. In which case you should remove the Posty class, or get very creative!

```
create_table "posts" do |t|
  t.integer  "target_id"
  t.string   "target_type", limit: 30
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :as => :target
end
```

Comment: In your 2nd choice, a post cannot be tagged to multiple targets (players, teams) right? since Post table will have just one record for each post and having target_id in the same table will not work. Correct me if this wrong!

Comment: That is correct. But, this is OK for a one-many relationship.